# Printing ASCII value of BB (HEX) in Unix

Tags: unix, character-encoding, solaris

When I am trying to paste the character » (right double angle quotes) in Unix from my Notepad, it's converting to /273. The corresponding Hex value is BB and the Decimal value is 187.

My actual requirement is to have this character as the file delimiter when I export a .dat file from a database table. So, this character was put in as the delimiter after each column name. But, while copy-pasting, it's getting converted to /273.

Any idea about how to fix this? I am on Solaris (SunOS 5.10).

Thanks,
Visakh

Comment: What are you pasting to ? What is displaying /273 ? I would expect something like � to be displayed with a mismatched locale. By the way 273 is the octal for 187.

Comment: I am pasting from Windows Notepad/Wordpad to the Unix vi editor.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII only defines the character codes up to 127 (0x7F) - everything after that is another encoding, such as ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8.   Make sure your locale is set to the encoding you are trying to use - the `locale` command will report your current locale settings, the [locale(5)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5175/locale-5.html) and [environ(5)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5175/environ-5.html) man pages cover how to set them.   A much more in-depth introduction to the whole character encoding concept can be found in [Joel Spolsky's *The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

The character code 0xBB is shown as `»` in the [IS0-8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO8859-1#Codepage_layout) character chart, so that's probably the character set you want, so the locale would be something like en_US.ISO8859-1 for that character set with US/English messages/date formats/currency settings/etc.

Comment: Thanks alanc. I have taken up the issue with then Unix admins.